# Custom function string aggregation in sequence PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

This is a custom function to aggregate strings in oracle.

```
 Date Fruit   Number
1      Apple    1
1      Apple    4
1      Apple    3
1      Kiwi     6
1      Kiwi     10
```

Turns to

```
Date     Fruit   Number
 1     Apple    1-3-4
 1     Kiwi     6-10
```

By using

```
 SELECT Date,fruit, string_agg(number) AS Agg
 FROM   fruit
 GROUP BY Date,fruit
```

string_agg is a function created by code below

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_string_agg AS OBJECT
(
  g_string  VARCHAR2(32767),

 STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg)
 RETURN NUMBER,

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                   value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
 RETURN NUMBER,

 MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_string_agg,
                                     returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                     flags        IN   NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER,

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                 ctx2  IN      t_string_agg)
RETURN NUMBER
);
/
SHOW ERRORS


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t_string_agg IS
STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_string_agg)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
sctx := t_string_agg(NULL);
RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                   value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
SELF.g_string := self.g_string || ',' || value;
RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_string_agg,
                                     returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                     flags        IN   NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
returnValue := RTRIM(LTRIM(SELF.g_string, ','), ',');
RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;

MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_string_agg,
                                 ctx2  IN      t_string_agg)
RETURN NUMBER IS
BEGIN
SELF.g_string := SELF.g_string || ',' || ctx2.g_string;
RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
END;
END;
/
 SHOW ERRORS


 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_agg (p_input VARCHAR2)
 RETURN VARCHAR2
 PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING t_string_agg;
 /
 SHOW ERRORS
```

But the problems I can't order string in sequence the way I want it to be. How do I modify the custom function code to make the aggregation in a certain sequence like order by number or something?

BTW: I'm version 10g, so I can't use listagg. Can this code be modified in order to order by a certain input? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do not reinvent wheel. Use **[`LISTAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm)**:

```
CREATE TABLE tab("Date" INT, Fruit VARCHAR(100), "Number" INT);

INSERT INTO tab  VALUES (1      ,'Apple',    1);
INSERT INTO tab  VALUES (1      ,'Apple',     4);
INSERT INTO tab  VALUES (1      ,'Apple',     3);
INSERT INTO tab  VALUES (1      ,'Kiwi',      6);
INSERT INTO tab  VALUES (1      ,'Kiwi',      10);


SELECT DISTINCT "Date", Fruit,
     LISTAGG ("Number" , '-') 
     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY "Date") OVER(PARTITION BY "Date", Fruit)  AS "Number"
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e1a5a/5/0)**</kbd>

*Warning:*

Keep in mind you need column to `ORDER BY`. In this case you don't have column with ascending orde and using `Date` which has all the same values may break if query will read data in different order. You should have something like:

```
ID Date Fruit   Number
1  1    Apple    1
2  1    Apple    4
3  1    Apple    3
4  1    Kiwi     6
5  1    Kiwi     10
```

And:

```
LISTAGG ("Number" , '-') 
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID ASC) OVER(PARTITION BY "Date", Fruit)  AS "Number"
```

**EDIT:**

**`LISTAGG`** is available from **Oracle 11**

Comment: Appreciate Lad, but I'm on version 10g(Listagg not supported)and I do wanna learn how to create customized function.

Comment: @SailorMoon Great, but for future be more specific with tags you use

Comment: yeah thanks! I didn't know I can put 10g there on the tag